# How to remove a layout param flag in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I know how to remove a flag layout params in Java. 
Its something like this `flags = flags & ~flag_not_wanted`,
but if i copy this to Kotlin it does not compile. What is the way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 13):

In Kotlin, to remove a flag we use `inv()` function.

```
flags = flags and flag_not_wanted.inv()
```